# If else in for each statement?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Is it possible to insert if else statement on for each

I would like to do add some if else statement on my for each.

I just want to set no value data to display as None.

and if it has value then it will return the data.

TABLE : wp_events_answer

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║  answer      ║question_id ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ Maybank      ║   12       ║
║  2 ║ no value     ║   12       ║
║  3 ║ no value     ║   12       ║
║  4 ║ CIMB         ║   12       ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

=

```
$number = 1;
foreach ($datas as $data) { 

    $result .= '<tbody>';                  
    $result .= '<tr>';
    $result .= '<td>';
    $result .= $number++;
    $result .= '</td>';

    $result .= '<td>';        
    $result .= $data->fname;
    $result .= '&nbsp;'; 
    $result .= $data->lname; 
    $result .= '</td>';

    $result .= '<td>';


    //#### PLEASE TAKE A LOOK HERE #####     
    if($result .= '')
    {
        $result .= 'None';
    }
    else
    {
        $result .= $data->answer;
    }

    //  #### END ####

    $result .= '</td>';
}
$result .= '</tr>';
$result .= '</table>';

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
    if(empty($data->answer))
    {
        $result .= 'None';
    }
    else
    {
        $result .= $data->answer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`if( $result .= '')` should be `if( !$data->answer)`.

If you're pedantic, you'd write `if( $data->answer === '')` but... well it's a bit silly in my opinion.

Comment: `$result` will always contain a value and be set.

Answer (score 0):

You have your condition wrong. The statement `$result .= ''` is not a comparison and (if PHP does what I think it does) always returns `true`. Instead, change it to `if( $data->answer == "" )` (or something like that) to actually compare your answer with an empty value.

Comment: It "always returns true" if the resulting `$result` is truthy. In this case, it is because the code is appending stuff to it already, but it might not be if `$result` were empty before.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your trying todo something like this (if not show expected HTML output and ill update):

```
<?php 
$number = 1;

$result = '
<table>
    <tbody>'.PHP_EOL;
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    //if $data->answer not empty
    if(!empty($data->answer)){
        $result .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.($number++).'</td>
            <td>'.htmlspecialchars($data->fname).'&nbsp;'.htmlspecialchars($data->lname).'</td>
            <td>'.$data->answer.'</td>
        </tr>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    //
    else{
        $result .= '
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">None</td>
        </tr>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$result  .= '
    </tbody>
</table>';

// returning from a function?
//return $result;

echo $result;
?>
```

You really went to town on the concatenation feature of PHP, took a while to understand what you are trying todo. Hope it helps ;p